# Cant connect to database: Loopback + Heroku + Postgres: ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432

Tags: postgresql, heroku, loopbackjs, loopback

I'm trying out loopback and I tried to push this test project to Heroku. The database can't connect with the error:
**Connection fails: ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432**

Database connects to my local postgres server just fine with my local credintials.

The database url credintial is the right one. I should have everything installed.

Here's datasources.json sample:

```
 "myDatabase": {
   "url": "[database url here]",
   "connector": "postgresql"}
```

What am I doing wrong or how should I try to fix this?

I cant migrate or start the server.

Answer (score 0):

first make sure that your postgresql is running on the port 5432.

A common PostgreSQL configuration is to connect to the UNIX domain socket /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432 instead of using the TCP/IP port. so your datasources.json should be something like:

```
{
    "myDatabase": {
        "host": "/var/run/postgresql/",
        "port": "5432",
        "database": "dbname",
        "username": "dbuser",
        "password": "dbpassword",
        "name": "postgres",
        "debug": true,
        "connector": "postgresql"
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but I looked in to this solution and it did not help. I think this has something to do with strongloop. I tried to deploy the same app in the AWS and there was similar problems. Thanks anyway!